# how to get all bases (a, b) of an expression such as (a[0]*b[0])?

Tags: python, sympy

Recently I reinstalled the anaconda and sympy. Then I run the same code for example as following, which gives me errors. (I don't have such error before)

```
import sympy as sp
a, b= sp.symbols('a b', cls=sp.IndexedBase)
l= sp.symbols('l', cls=sp.Wild)

def Bfunc(expr,p1,p2):
    if expr.base==p1:return expr.replace(p1[l],0.2*(p2[l]+p1[-l]),map=False, simultaneous=True, exact=True)
    else: return expr.replace(p2[l],0.2*(p1[l]+p2[-l]),map=False, simultaneous=True, exact=True)      

inputstate=a[0]*b[0]
psi0=inputstate.replace(lambda expr: expr.base in [a,b], lambda expr: Bfunc(expr,a,b))
```

It gives me the error:

[image]

The problem is **expr.base**, which cannot gives the base **a** or **b**.

Let's look at a very simple example:

```
import sympy as sp
a, b= sp.symbols('a b', cls=sp.IndexedBase)
l= sp.symbols('l', cls=sp.Wild)    

inputstate=a[0]*b[0]
inputstate.base
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-7cc51ba4a4cd>", line 6, in <module>
    inputstate.base

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'base'
```

If the ***inputstate=a[0]***, then ***inputstate.base*** gives you ***a***.

So I wonder why such error happens after I reinstalled the sympy and anaconda. Or is there any way to give all the base list and fix the error?

If someone has similar cases, would be very cool if you can give me some hints. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foo` function returns None when it encounters an Attribute error and this signals to `replace` that nothing should be done at that node. When you use the lambda, there is nothing to catch the error so the process raises the error to your attention. One option would be to change `replace` so it ignores errors and just skips the node. The good thing about *not* doing that, however, is that it alerts you to the fact that you are doing something in a way that will miss objects you wanted to handle. So to use the lambda you have to help it succeed at identifying the terms of interest.

```
>>> L1 = lambda x: x.is_Pow and x.base in [a, b]
>>> inputstate.replace(L1, lambda expr: Bfunc(expr,a,b))
a[0]*b[0]
>>> L2 = lambda x: x.as_base_exp()[0] in [a, b]
>>> inputstate.replace(L1, lambda expr: Bfunc(expr,a,b))
a[0]*b[0]
```

(I prefer L1 because it uses a quick `is_Pow` test to know whether one is dealing with a power or not. Your Bfunc assumes it is dealing with a power, so L2 will not work for all cases unless you also modify *it* to deal with the non-Pow case.)

One question to answer is whether you want to target actual powers or also "powers" with an exponent of 1. For example if you wanted to raise the exponents of all powers by 1 would you want `x*y**2 -> x**2*y**3` or just `x*y**3`? L1 would be good for the first case and L2 for the second.

Comment: Let's say `test1=a[0]**2`, `test1.is_Pow`  gives you _True_ ; `test1=a[0]*b[0]`, `test1.is_Pow`  gives you _False_ . Also if I run  `test1=a[0]*b[0]+b[2]*b[2]`,
`test1.is_Pow and test1.base in [a, b]`, the result gives _False_ . All these mean the function `Bfunc(expr,a,b)` will not be excluded, which is not I want.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the output you would like to see for an input case that is not working? I showed in the L1/L2 example that no error is raised for the `inputstate` that you gave...but it also didn't do anything.

Comment: OK: change `expr.base` to `expr.base.base` in `L1` and in `Bfunc`; the first base gives you the base of the `Pow` and the second gives you the base of the `Indexed` (which is what you are passing). In addition, set `exact=False` in `Bfunc` and all should work: `(a[0]**2).replace(L1, lambda expr: Bfunc(expr, a, b)) -> (0.2*a[0] + 0.2*b[0])**2`

Comment: The fact that `exact=True` fails on 1 symbol is a bug and the issue page at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/16725 has been updated to reflect that.

Comment: But this only works for something like `a[0]**2`, what if I use `a[1]*b[1]` or more complicated  expressions such as `a[1]*b[1]+a[2]+b[3]`, this will not work because of `expr.is_Pow` gives _False_ .

Comment: I also try to make `exact=Flase`, still not work. I don't know how to say in the comment very well. So I put my comment with "answer" to show the `Bfunctest(expr,a,b)` doesn't work. Thank you!  @smichr

Comment: Ahh. That's what I meant when I asked "whether you want to target actual powers". What do you want each of those to become?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192982/discussion-between-smichr-and-xuemei-gu).

Comment: The issue was resolved -- see the link to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an `IndexedBase`, and `a[0]` is an `Indexed` object, whose `base is`a`:

```
In [21]: type(a)                                                                
Out[21]: sympy.tensor.indexed.IndexedBase
In [22]: type(a[0])                                                             
Out[22]: sympy.tensor.indexed.Indexed
In [23]: a[0].base                                                              
Out[23]: a

In [25]: inputstate=a[0]*b[0]                                                   
In [26]: inputstate                                                             
Out[26]: a[0]*b[0]
In [27]: type(inputstate)                                                       
Out[27]: sympy.core.mul.Mul
```

`inputstate` is `Mul` `expr` object.  It's not `Indexed`, so doesn't have a base.

Do you have a record of 'correct' behavior in earlier versions of `sympy`, or evidence of some sort of change in the documentation.  In what version did it work?

Your `Bfunc` and `replace` appear to work for me:

```
In [51]: ab = inputstate.replace(lambda expr: expr.base in [a,b], lambda expr: Bfunc(expr,a,b))                                                        
In [52]: ab                                                                     
Out[52]: a[0]*b[0]
In [53]: type(ab)                                                               
Out[53]: sympy.core.mul.Mul
```

What change am I supposed to see?

```
In [55]: sp.__version__                                                         
Out[55]: '1.3'
```

---

If I change the `replace` lambda with a small function:

```
In [71]: def foo(expr): 
    ...:     try: 
    ...:         print(expr, expr.base) 
    ...:         return expr.base in [a,b] 
    ...:     except AttributeError: 
    ...:         print(expr) 
    ...:          
    ...:                                                                        
In [72]: ab = inputstate.replace(foo, lambda expr: Bfunc(expr,a,b))             
a
a
0
a[0] a
b
b
0
b[0] b
a[0]*b[0]
```

It appears that `replace` passes various elements of the `expr` to this function.  Error such as this `AttributeError` are ignored.

The 1.4 release notes has something about `replace` and its `exact` parameter.  I wonder using `exact=False` would fix things in 1.4 (I can't test that without ungrading).

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace

Comment: Thank you!  I don't have a record of the earlier behavior. But I don't have a error when I run `inputstate.replace(lambda expr: expr.base in [a,b], lambda expr: Bfunc(expr,a,b)) ` in the earlier version but now gives me error. It's the same code and I didn't do anything. I'm confused...

Comment: It seems to run for me on 1.13, though I don't know what change I should be looking for.

Comment: after reinstalling and updating, my sp version now is `1.4`.

Comment: thank you very much! I uninstall the sympy and install the earlier version '1.3'. The codes work and there are no errors. But I still don't get what the update changes.

Comment: although I change `exact=False`, in 1.4 version the code still gives me the error. I will look up the 1.4 release notes. You help me a lot. Thank you very much:) @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

let's say the following codes:

```
import sympy as sp
a, b= sp.symbols('a b', cls=sp.IndexedBase)
l= sp.symbols('l', cls=sp.Wild)

def Bfunctest(expr,p1,p2):
    if expr.base==p1:return expr.replace(p1[l],0.2*p1[-l],map=False, simultaneous=True, exact=False)
    else: return expr.replace(p2[l],0.2*p2[-l],map=False, simultaneous=True, exact=False)

L1 = lambda expr: expr.is_Pow and expr.base in [a, b]
inputstate=a[1]*b[1]
out=inputstate.replace(L1, lambda expr: Bfunctest(expr,a,b))
```

The output is `a[1]*b[1]` not `0.04*a[-1]*b[-1]`, which means **`Bfunctest()`** is not excluded.

because `inputstate.is_Pow and inputstate.base in [a, b]` gives you *False*. It happens in the case when you use `inputstate.as_base_exp()[0] in [a, b]`, which gives *False*. So the **`Bfunctest()`** will not be excluded.